# Como enviar e-mail com corpo e com anexo usando smtplib e email em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, envio-de-email

Quando envio um e-mail simples em Python utilizando apenas a biblioteca smtplib, posso escrever no corpo do e-mail através do argumento "mensagem" da função do seguinte script:

```
def enviaremail(usuario,senha,mensagem,listadestinatarios):
    from smtplib import SMTP
    smtp=SMTP('smtp.live.com',587)
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(usuario,senha)
    smtp.sendmail(usuario,listadestinatarios,mensagem)
    smtp.quit()
    print('E-mail enviado com sucesso')
enviaremail('xxxx@hotmail.com','xxxx','ola mundo',['xxxx@hotmail.com']
```

Porém, quando vou enviar um e-mail com anexo, tenho que usar a biblioteca email. Um exemplo de envio de e-mail com imagem como anexo é:

```
def enviaremail(usuario,senha,mensagem,listadestinatarios):
    from smtplib import SMTP
    smtp=SMTP('smtp.live.com',587)
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(usuario,senha)
    smtp.sendmail(usuario,listadestinatarios,mensagem)
    smtp.quit()
    print('E-mail enviado com sucesso')
def anexoimagem(path):
    from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
    with open(path,'rb') as f:
        mime=MIMEImage(f.read(),subtype='jpg')
    return mime
msg=anexoimagem('foto.jpg')
msg['From']='xxxx@hotmail.com'
msg['To']='xxxx@hotmail.com'
msg['Subject']='testando mensagem com anexo'
enviaremail('xxxx@hotmail.com','xxxx',msg.as_string,['xxxx@hotmail.com']
```

O problema é que a mensagem passa a ser o anexo, e não o corpo do e-mail, como no caso anterior. A pergunta é: como posso adicionar um corpo para o e-mail nesse segundo script? Como enviar um e-mail com corpo e anexo juntos?

Comment: Há aqui duas respostas com boa votação que talvez ajudem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python

Comment: Bom, não é duplicata *per se*, mas na minha resposta pra sua outra pergunta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178078/como-enviar-um-arquivo-como-anexo-por-e-mail-sem-que-ele-seja-automaticamente-re) tem exatamente isso. Faltou um pouco de atenção da sua parte. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após pesquisar mais, descobri que o objeto MIMEText, além de armazenar anexos de texto, também pode armazenar o corpo do e-mail. A seguinte função retorna um objeto MIME armazenando um arquivo .txt.

```
def anexotexto(path):
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    with open(path,'r') as f:
        mime=MIMEText(f.read(),_subtype='txt')
    return mime
```

Já a seguinte função retorna um objeto MIME armazenando o corpo do e-mail.

```
def mensagem(string):
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    mime=MIMEText(string)
    return mime
```