# Como enviar um arquivo como anexo por e-mail sem que ele seja automaticamente renomeado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, envio-de-email

Sou iniciante em enviar e-mails através de script e estou enfrentando um problema. Uso Python 3.5. Ao enviar anexos com o seguinte script, eles perdem a extensão e são renomeados:

```
def enviaremail(usuario,senha,mensagem,listadestinatarios):
    from smtplib import SMTP
    smtp=SMTP('smtp.live.com',587)
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(usuario,senha)
    smtp.sendmail(usuario,listadestinatarios,mensagem)
    smtp.quit()
    print('E-mail enviado com sucesso')
def anexoimagem(path):
    from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
    with open(path,'rb') as f:
        mime=MIMEImage(f.read(),subtype='jpg')
    return mime
msg=anexoimagem('foto.jpg')
msg['From']='xxxx@hotmail.com'
msg['To']='xxxx@hotmail.com'
msg['Subject']='testando mensagem com anexo'
enviaremail('xxxx@hotmail.com','xxxx',msg.as_string,['xxxx@hotmail.com']
```

Por exemplo, o arquivo foto.jpg aparece como ATT0001 no e-mail. Renomeado e sem a extensão .jpg que ele tem. O mesmo acontece com arquivos de texto e de áudio. Como faço para os arquivos manterem seu nome e extensão ao serem enviados como anexos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não está definindo o nome do anexo, por isso um nome gerado está sendo utilizado. Experimente trocando a linha:

```
mime=MIMEImage(f.read(),subtype='jpg')
```

por:

```
mime=MIMEImage(f.read(),subtype='jpg', name=os.path.basename(path))
```

Naturalmente, para usar a função `basename` você vai precisar fazer a importação do pacote `os`:

```
import os
```

Você também pode indicar o nome do arquivo no cabeçalho do conteúdo MIME antes da chamada de `enviaremail`:

```
msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='foto.jpg')
```

Veja [esse exemplo](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email-examples.html#id2) na documentação.

### Edição

Eis aqui um pequeno código de exemplo que faz exatamente isso: lê uma imagem do arquivo com o nome `"img.jpg"` e a envia no email como se o seu nome fosse `"Ó o auê aí, ô.jpg"`:

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

smtp_server = '<seu servidor aqui>'
smtp_port = <porta>
acc_addr = '<seu email aqui>'
acc_pwd = '<sua senha aqui>'

to_addr = '<seu destinatário aqui>'
subject = 'Teste do SOPT!'
body = 'Este é um teste de envio de email via Python!'

# Configura o servidor de envio (SMTP)
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
server.starttls()
server.login(acc_addr, acc_pwd)

# Cria o documento com várias partes
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = acc_addr
msg["To"] = to_addr
msg["Subject"] = subject

# Anexa a imagem
imgFilename = 'Ó o auê aí, ô.jpg' # Repare que é diferente do nome do arquivo local!
with open('img.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    msgImg = MIMEImage(f.read(), name=imgFilename)
msg.attach(msgImg)

# Anexa o corpo do texto
msgText = MIMEText('<b>{}</b><br><img src="cid:{}"><br>'.format(body, imgFilename), 'html')
msg.attach(msgText)

# Envia!
server.sendmail(acc_addr, to_addr, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu queria algo relacionado à sua primeira sugestão, porém deu erro. Disse que o argumento "name" não existe em __init__ do MIMEImage. Será que não tem algo parecido com isso que funcione, @luiz?

Comment: Bom, eu acabei de testar aqui (novamente) e funcionou. E a minha versão também é 3.5. Deve ter algo errado no seu código. Vou editar a resposta e adicionar o código de teste que eu usei.

Comment: Tentei sua segunda dica e funcionou. Mesmo a primeira não funcionando para mim, deve funcionar para outros, já que funcionou no seu script. Enfim, obrigado. A segunda dica resolveu meu problema.